# Query to update the content of a cell using

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table with the following format:

```
column1   column2
   40       blue
   20       red
```

I have I would like to update the contain of my column based on a value entered a `TextBox` and a `comboBox`, for example if I select red from my `comboBox` and enter the value 30 in my `TextBox` , I would like my table to be updated as follow

```
column1   column2
   40       blue
   50       red
```

I thought of something like this:

```
update tablename set column1=....+TextBox.Text where column2=ComboBox.Text
```

My question how do I get the current content of that row? do I need a query to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the other responses, you should also be using parameterized query:

```
connection.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE table SET column1 = column1 + @column1 WHERE column2 = @column2", connection);
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
adp.UpdateCommand = command;
adp.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@column1", SqlDbType.Int));
adp.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@column2", SqlDbType.VarChar));
adp.UpdateCommand.Parameters["@column1"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox.Text);
adp.UpdateCommand.Parameters["@column2"].Value = ComboBox.Text;
try
{
    adp.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: I updated using what you suggested but I have the following error : No value given for one or more required parameters. I am not sure what the problem is

Comment: @user3841581 It's because I used single quotes on the query that updates the table, you should always use double quotes... I'm so sorry. Change that and let me know how it went.

Answer (score 2):

You are so close.  You can just reference the column:

```
update tablename
    set column1 = column1 + TextBox.Text
    where column2 = ComboBox.Text;
```

I should note that you should not be constructing the query from user input.  You should be parameterizing the query.  There are two important reasons.  The first is to prevent unexpected syntax errors.  The second is to guard against SQL injection.

If you are just learning to program with SQL, then using parameters is doubly important.  You don't want to start learning bad habits.

Answer (score 1):

directly pass the column name as shown below

```
update tablename set column1=column1+TextBox.Text where column2=ComboBox.Text
```